# Acces to global namespace with ava testing

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, ava

I'm using "ava" framework for react testing, here is a piece of package.json:

```
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "es2015",
      "stage-2",
      "react"
    ]
  },
  "ava": {
    "babel": "inherit",
    "require": [
      "babel-register"
    ]
  }
```

code of test:

```
import store from '../../app/redux/store';
 import test from 'ava';
import * as c from '../../app/constants'

test('languageReducer() should correctly change the dictionary', t => {
  store.dispatch({
    type: c.LOCALIZE_CHANGE_DICTIONARY,
    dictionary: {
      a: 1,
      b: 2,
      c: 3
    }
  });

  t.DeepEqual(store.getState().localizeReducer.dictionary, {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3});

  t.is(10, 10);
});
```

and there is error sounds like :

```
unsubscribeHistory = history.listen(function (location) {
                            ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'listen' of undefined
    at middleware      (/Users/nikita/WebstormProjects/crm_panel/node_modules/redux-simple-  router/lib/index.js:72:33)
```

What should I do to give my tests access to global namespace(window, history, etc.) ?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It seems you're trying to use a browser module, that tries to use the browser global `history`, without actually running the test in the browser. AVA doesn't yet run in the browser, but you can use [jsdom](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom) to provide a fake browser environment. We have a [recipe for this](https://github.com/sindresorhus/ava/blob/master/docs/recipes/browser-testing.md).